# Trying to include both a select statement and user input in an insert statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I'm trying to create a small-scale payroll system as practice, utilizing WPF as an interface and connecting to a SQL Server database. I'm setting up the stored procedures, and I'm trying to arrange one to add a new work shift to the database. It takes user input for the employee's first and last name, then inserts a new shift, inputting the manually entered details, along with inserting an employee ID from the tblEmployee table where the employee's first and last name are the same as the user-input first and last name. Problem is that it's giving me an incorrect syntax error for the last line, and I can't seem to figure out why.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE NewShift(
@LName varchar(50),
@FName varchar(50),
@Date date,
@ShiftStart time,
@ShiftEnd time,
@HoursWorked decimal(18,2)
)
AS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO tblShifts(
EmpID,
Date,
ShiftStart,
ShiftEnd,
HoursWorked
)


SELECT EmpID, @Date, @ShiftStart, @ShiftEnd, @HoursWorked
FROM tblEmployee WHERE LName=@LName AND FName=@FName
```

Comment: Missing `END` keyword at the end

Comment: Welp. That's fixed. And is also my cue to stop doing anything that requires thinking for the day. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

`DATE` is a keyword word and probably reserved (depends on the version and reserved by ODBC), so it is a lousy name for a column:

```
INSERT INTO tblShifts(EmpID, [Date], ShiftStart, ShiftEnd, HoursWorked)
    SELECT EmpID, @Date, @ShiftStart, @ShiftEnd, @HoursWorked
    FROM tblEmployee
    WHERE LName = @LName AND FName = @FName;
```

Of course, you also need the `END` for the end of the stored procedure.

Comment: OMG Someone downvoted Gordon's answer I will not allow that to happen :D..    +1 to nullify the downvote since the original problem is addressed

Comment: One reason I can think of is, Since it is a procedure it will be called though exec from application layer so `date` present in column should not have any impact.. May be am wrong just my guess

Comment: @GordonLinoff I am sorry . I thought missing END was the issue. So how can i  undo that downvote ?

Comment: @RohitPadma . . . The missing end is definitely an issue and *the* issue if the OP showed the entire body of code.  It is still a bad idea to call a column `date`.

Comment: Yeah date is allowed as column and it allows in the stored procedure. I was able to execute the above mentioned scenario. so i had down voted @GordonLinoff  But the tricky part is Date is not allowed. so  my bad :(

Comment: yeah I agree with you. having a column with reserved Keywords is always a bad  idea. @GordonLinoff

Comment: @RohitPadma - now click on down button it will remove the vote

Comment: @Prdp Thanks for that Edit. :)

Comment: @RohitPadma - Remember you cannot downvote and go just like that. You need to comment what is wrong or why did you downvote

Comment: @Prdp Chill dude ! I gave a explanation  why i down voted. I realized the mistake... that's reason i commented immediately and up voted again So Relax.

Comment: Noted on all accounts, and upvoted pretty much every constructive answer - I'm still fairly new to this, so getting used to good practices is a good idea too.